# How to make a Column header a hyperlink

Tags: list, hyperlink

I am making a dashboard that shows what countries have different stuff. I want to be able to click on the column header which would represent a country and have it link to a list that is specific to that country. Please help.

Comment: Should we assume that it's not an option to display the country name in a field and attach the link to this instead?  Do you have a picture, it might help to fire our imaginations!